# Is there a feature/formula in Google Sheets that can Transfer info to another sheet if the checkbox is clicked?

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say we have 3 sheets, and a employee Jeff.
The Sheets are:
`All Employees`
`Employee's Payments`
`Employee's Fired`

Is there a formula, condition, filter or what-not where if I press on a checkbox, it blacks-out/deletes Jeff from "All Employee's" and "Employee's Payments", and moves his info to the "Employee's Fired" sheet.
And if I remove the check-mark on his info, he gets added back, and removed from the "Employee's Fired" sheet?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=FILTER('Employee''s Fired'!A2:A, 'Employee''s Fired'!B2:B<>TRUE, 'Employee''s Fired'!B2:B<>"")
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rA4nSSva75I7JBa7C3EgeTEMtBJaAAIJgDOUXtu9qrE/copy)